# error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: c#, .net

I'm beginner in this, I have been created web application by using ASP.NET and  C# after deployment when I open my project in the browser I have this error

This page contains the following errors:
    error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Please help me I searched many web sites to solve this error for three days now and I didn't find any solution

Login.aspx code

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="E.I.I_User_Interface.Login1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            color: #000000;
        }
        .style4
        {
            font-size: medium;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            color: #000000;
            text-align: right;
            width: 145px;
        }
        .style5
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .style6
        {
            width: 180px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .style7
        {
            width: 58px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="color: #74E7D6; background-color: #DDDDDD; text-align:center;
    width:auto; max-width:500PX">
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>

        <img src="images/E.I.I_logo.png" alt="" 
            style="width:101px; height: 116px; text-align: center" /></td>
            <td>
                        <img src="images/E.I.I_name.png" alt="" 
                    style="width:699px; height: 113px"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                LOGIN</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="errorMsgLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    User Name</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UNLoginTextBox" runat="server" style="text-align: left" 
                        Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="UNLoginTextBox" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    Password</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="pwdLoginTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                        Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="pwdLoginTextBox" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <p>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style6">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="SignupButton" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/signUp.png" PostBackUrl="~/CreateUser.aspx" 
                        ToolTip="Sign Up" Width="50px" CausesValidation="False" 
                        onclick="SignupButton_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="style7" style="text-align: left">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Height="50px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/login.png" ToolTip="Login" 
                        Width="50px" onclick="LoginButton_Click" style="text-align: left" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="changePasswordButton" runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="False" Font-Size="Medium" 
                        onclick="changePasswordButton_Click">Change Password</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show your code where are you getting error.

Comment: Hi Shady welcome to stackoverflow, please read this thread to improve the quality of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't have ASP.NET feature installed in IIS.

Run "appwiz.cpl" -> Turn windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> Check everything in the list and click OK.